# make a number move up a value or down

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm trying to make a calculator and I'm trying to make a number move up or down a value (ie if I have 1 and press 2 I want it to be 12 and make a number move into a decimal)

```
<script>
var calcval1=0;
var calcval2=0;
var calcdis=1;
document.getElementById("DISl").value =calcdis;
function add1()
{
calcdis+1;
calcdis<<=0;
}
</script>
```

tried using bitwise but i am new so i didn't know how to use it properly :(

Comment: Can you please post your relevant code? It's difficult to help if we can't see where you are =)

Comment: something like this? https://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/pwgKby

Comment: @DanielH, i think he means that he wants the number to be formatted to decimal automatically. Like: type 12, display 1,2.

Comment: Can you look at any of the other 690 [`[javascript] [calculator]` questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+and+%5Bcalculator%5D) and see if you can find the answer yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to move the first character over, you can just replace the old data with the new data:

```js
// Get the text field
var txt = document.getElementById("calc");

// Get all the buttons
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

// Loop through them and add a click event listener to each

Array.prototype.slice.call(buttons).forEach(function(btn){
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    calc.value += this.textContent;
  })
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="calc">
<button id="btn1">1</button>
<button id="btn2">2</button>
<button id="btn3">3</button>
<button id="btn4">4</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing your display number in a single variable you would need to multiply or divide by 10 every time, if you working with decimal base.

Or it could be an array of digits, that you shift positions.

Comment: *an array of digits* also called string.

Comment: @Jonasw No it's not. An array of digits is an array of digits. A group of characters is called a string. `digit !== string`, `character === string`

Comment: @scott marcus i was refering to question context

Comment: this question is tagged with "calculator"

Comment: @Jonasw So, was I.

Answer (score 0):

You need to shift the number left. As you're working in the decimal system (based on the powers of 10) you can just multiply your current number with 10 and add the new digit. Let's go through an example:

Initial number:

```
x = 0
```

`1` is pressed; you need to update your number

```
x = 10 * x + 1 // = 1
```

`2` is pressed; you need to update your number

```
x = 10 * x + 2 // = 12
```

I assume you understand the pattern here.

Comment: ive commented the second = out, cause it would be a syntax error when somebody has the idea of copying it into his console... feel free to roll back